# Quiero crear una etiqueta que permita ver un progreso de Progress Bar

Tags: java, java-swing

He creado un ProgressBar en Java y funciona bien, pero quiero crear un etiqueta que vaya acorde al progreso y me diga cuánto voy avanzando, es decir, mientras se va llenando la barrita quiero que vaya avanzando una numeración que vaya del 0 al 100 %

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar un switch, a donde puedas poner en cada caso el progreso que quieres que te visualice y en cada caso ponerle el porcentaje que quiera quieres que se muestre.

case 30:
break;
case 60:
break;
case 100:
break;

Espero que te sirva de algo o si era lo que buscabas.